# AngularJS HTML sub routes not showing when url typed in

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have AngularJS setup to use HTML5 routes and it works great on urls like **website.com/foo** but when I create routes for sub pages, eg: **website.com/foo/bar** it only shows the correct page when clicking a link to it on my site. If I type the url into my browser and attempt to directly access it I get a blank page section where the ng-view content should be loading.

```
    app.when('/promotion/events', {
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/promotion/events/home.html',
        controller: PromotionEventsCtrl
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug in Angular 1.1.5 that is effecting URL parsing in HTML5 routes. Rolling back to 1.1.4 fixes the problem.

More information here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2833